# SSIS Full load & incremental in same package?

Tags: ssis, etl

Need some design ideas on how to have the full load and incremental load in the same same package. I want to build two separate control flow one each for full & incremental load in the same package. I know I can use some variable but sure how to do it. Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you please go through this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. StackOverflow community is not a community to get your complete code. If you run into any problems the community can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking for the complete code. I am looking for how it could be done in best possible way. Do I need to have a table in DB through which I control what parameter to pass or is there a way it can be controlled in SSIS.

Comment: This is too broad for a forum question.   There are articles written about how to do this.

Comment: Could you point me to few of these articles? Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach would be to have a date control table with 2 columns (FullLoadDate and IncrementalLoadDate)

For full load keep a static begining date  and pass that in your workflow.

For incremental load, set an initial date then let the date update after daily load to pass it as an incremental condition for next day's load.